# How to turn off double tap to wake on Lumia 640 XL on Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia-640-xl

How to turn off double tap to wake up the device on my Lumia 640 XL on Windows 10 Mobile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go under settings, then search for touch. You can go directly go under `Settings > Extras`.

Under there you will see the `touch` option:

[image]

Then under the option, you will see the option to turn off double tap to wake up.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Settings-> Extras-> Touch-> Wake up the phone when i double tap on the screen (On/Off)

Comment: I don't have "touch" command.

Comment: really???? what build are you on now? Or wait, download **Touch** app,           https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/gestures-touch/9nblggh319dm